# Should I reinforce the cupboard back before mounting it to the wall?

Tags: hanging

I have a cupboard/shelf that is like a bookshelf with a back and sliding glass doors. It weighs 10kg without the glass and without anything in it.

I want to attach it to the wall and have read about that side of things, but I am worried about the cupboard back itself. Will it gradually get damaged by holding all its weight just on little screws?

Therefore -  should I just put screws through it into the wall studs? Should I reinforce the cupboard back where the screws go? Should I do some other thing?

The cupboard is second hand and appears to have been just attached directly to a wall with screws previously. The backing panel is better quality than cardboard, but not heavy wood.

Comment: Please provide a picture of the back of the cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the shelves are attached to the back of the cupboard or the sides. They are effectively transferring weight from the contents to their attachments, which is why most cupboards with shelves attached to sides have the sides attached to the walls using some form of bracket.

One way to ensure that the cupboard is supported properly is to attach a piece of lumber to the wall along the bottom of the cupboards, they then effective sit on it. This of course assumes you have the space to do this, and that the lumber will not look bad if viewing it from the bottom.

You can do the same thing towards the top of the back by having a piece of lumber that screws into the sides (from the back) and runs the length of the cupboard. This can then be screwed through from inside the cupboard to provide extra strength. The downside of this is that it will mean the cupboard will sit away from the wall the thickness of the lumber. You would also put this piece towards the top of the back of the cupboard, but usually not right at the top, although having at the top would not be a problem. There needs to be enough space to screw through.

Combined, the lumber below the cupboard supports the weight of the cupboard and contents, with the piece at the top preventing it from falling forward.

Comment: @wallyk - Happy with some of your grammatical modifications, but changing timber to lumber assumes this is a US only site and actually I find those edits offensive.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I meant to be clearer but had no idea such language wasn't universal English.  So does a Brit call a pile of felled trees?  How about a log ready for milling?